# mongoimport failed to import JSON data

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoimport

I'm trying to import a file called breedData.json into mongodb following the steps in this article http://zaiste.net/2012/08/importing_json_into_mongodb/.

So I enter the command below in terminal from my app's root folder.  The breedData.json file is also in the app root folder.  Mongod and nodemon are running.

```
mongoimport --db shelterdoggie --collection breeds --type json --file breedData.json --jsonArray
```

and I get this:

```
2015-09-07T00:58:18.646-0700    connected to: localhost
2015-09-07T00:58:18.647-0700    Failed: error reading separator after document #2: bad JSON array format - found '{' outside JSON object/array in input source
2015-09-07T00:58:18.647-0700    imported 0 documents
```

I've checked my file with jsonlint.com and it is valid json.

I've tried using this json format with the above Terminal command:

```
[
{"malehw":"Ht: 9-11.5, Wt: 7-9","femalehw":"Ht: 9-11.5, Wt: 7-9"},
{"malehw":"Ht: 27, Wt: 60","femalehw":"Ht: 25, Wt: 50"},
{"malehw":"Ht: 23, Wt: 45","femalehw":"Ht: <23, Wt: 45"}
]
```

and I've also tried this format, while leaving off the --jsonArray flag in the command above:

```
{"malehw":"Ht: 9-11.5, Wt: 7-9","femalehw":"Ht: 9-11.5, Wt: 7-9"}
{"malehw":"Ht: 27, Wt: 60","femalehw":"Ht: 25, Wt: 50"}
{"malehw":"Ht: 23, Wt: 45","femalehw":"Ht: <23, Wt: 45"}
```

but then I get this error:

```
2015-09-07T01:11:00.034-0700    connected to: localhost
2015-09-07T01:11:00.035-0700    Failed: error processing document #1: invalid character '{' after array element
2015-09-07T01:11:00.035-0700    imported 0 documents
```

I've checked the file and there are 152 {'s and 152 }'s and I have 152 rows/documents in my file, so it shouldn't be due to an unclosed curly brace somewhere.  I don't understand why this isn't working.  If you have any suggestions, I'd appreciate it.

Here's one full line from my .json file in case it helps:

```
{"malehw":"Ht: 24-26, Wt: 75-95","femalehw":"Ht: 22-24, Wt: 75-95","catfriendly":"••••","easytraining":"••••••","watchdog":"••••••","grooming":"•••","coldtolerant":"••••","care":"Among the most intelligent of breeds, the German Shepherd Dog is so intent on his mission whatever that may be and he is virtually unsurpassed in working versatility. He is utterly devoted and faithful. He is usually good with other pets.","breed":"German Shepherd Dog","health":"This breed needs daily mental and physical challenges. He enjoys a good exercise session as well as learning session. He is family-oriented and does well as a house dog. His coat needs brushing one or two times weekly.","energy":"••••","playfulness":"•••","dogfriendly":"••","strangerfriendly":"•••","protection":"••••••","heattolerant":"••••","exercise":"•••••","affection":"••••","index":67,"url":"https://www.petfinder.com/dog-breeds/German-Shepherd-Dog"}
```

Comment: I'm able to run all your queries without any error, even i created a array of the final one full line(just replicated the same line) and still it is working fine in my shell. check whether you are referring the correct file and the path.

Comment: Also, I'm using MongoDB shell version: 3.0.4.  I'm running the Terminal command from the shelter_doggie directory, and the breedData.json file is in that directory at the top level.  I also tried exporting the data as a csv file and importing using: `mongoimport -db shelterdoggie --collection breeds --type csv --file kimonoData.csv --headerline` but I got this error `error validating settings: incompatible options: --file and positional argument(s)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Clement's suggestion put me on the right track. Putting the full file path for the file worked.  The import command in Terminal looked like this:

```
mongoimport --db shelterdoggie --collection breeds --type json --file ~/dev/shelter_doggie/breedData.json --jsonArray
```

As for my csv import attempt, I only had one dash before db instead of two dashes. I fixed that and added the full file path for the csv file. So it works when I run the command like this:

```
mongoimport --db shelterdoggie --collection breeds --type csv --file ~/dev/shelter_doggie/kimonoData.csv --headerline
```

Not sure if there's another way to do this without the full file path (as the article in my initial question indicates), but at least I can import my data.

Comment: if you want to use relative path just remove --file and try.. it will work.. mongoimport takes positional arguments and considers it as value for file

**mongoimport.exe -d shelterdoggie  -c breeds --type csv ..\something\test1.csv --headerline**

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem on Windows so fixed it by passing the data via stdin example

```
cat "PATH\breedData.json" | mongoimport.exe --db shelterdoggie --collection breeds --type json --file --jsonArray
```

or on Linux

```
mongoimport --db shelterdoggie --collection breeds --type json --file --jsonArray < breedData.json
```

Comment: I get an error "file doesn't exist: --jsonArray" in Linux

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same problem and I appened the --jsonArray while importing the collection and it worked

```
 mongoimport -u abc --authenticationDatabase abc --file=/home/ubuntu/collection_name.json  --jsonArray --collection=collection_name --db=abc
```